# Sum of the eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

if $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $t \in \mathcal L (V,V) $is such that $t^2 = id_V$ prove that the sum of eigenvalues of t is an integer.

I started the prove as such:

Let $\lambda_1 ,...,\lambda_n $ be eigenvalues of $t$.

So $\lambda_1^2 ,... \lambda_n^2$ will be the eigenvalues  for  $t^2 = id_V$

I don't how to continue. Any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You know $X^2-1=(X-1)(X+1)$ annihilates $t$. What can be the possible eigenvalues for $t$?

Comment: $+- 1$ are possible eigenvalues

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues are 1 or -1, hence the sum is an integer. 
The fact that the eigenvalues are $\pm1$ can be proved as follows: if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue and $v$ an eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda$, then $v=t^2(v)=\lambda^2 v$, hence $\lambda=\pm1$.